# How to replace the nth occurrence of a string using sed

Tags: sed

Is there any way to replace the nth occurrence of a string in a file using sed?

I'm using  `sed -i '0,/jack.*/ s//jill/'` to replace the first occurrence.

How can i change it so that it replaces the nth occurrence?

My file contents the following lines:

```
first line
second line
third line
jack=1
fifth line
jack=
seventh line
```

I don't know the value after `jack=`, it can be anything or nothing.

I want to replace the 2nd occurrence of `jack=` and anything that follows it with `jill`.

Answer (score 32):

First replace all the newlines with a unique character that does not occur anywhere else in your file (e.g. `^`) using `tr`. You need to do this in order to create a single string for `sed`. Then pass it to `sed` and tell it to replace the nth occurrence of your string. Finally, pass the output back through `tr` to recreate the newlines.

For n=2, the command is:

```
$ tr '\n' '^' < file | sed 's/jack/jill/2' | tr '^' '\n'
first line
second line
third line
jack
fifth line
jill
seventh line
```

**Update:**

It can also be done with `sed`, WITHOUT changing the newlines first, using the following command:

```
$ sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/jack/jill/2' file
```

Alternatively, use `awk`:

```
$ awk '/jack/{c+=1}{if(c==2){sub("jack","jill",$0)};print}' file
```

Comment: no, it won't update the input file. You can redirect the output to a different file by adding `> outputfile` to the end of the command.

Comment: You can do this without messing up the newlines, using hold space. Push all lines into hold space using `h` and `H`, swap hold and pattern space, do the substitute, and print.

Comment: i tried $ sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/jack/jill/2' file
but in my file the word jack can be followed by other characters e.g 
jack= i want to replace jack and the characters that follows jack as well with a new string i tried 
$ sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/jack.*/jill/2' file but it didnt work.

Comment: can you please update your file contents in the question to show what you want?

Comment: try: `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/jack[^\n]*/jill/2' file`

Comment: I suggest editing the "Update" to be the main answer. That updated solution worked for me (and it is more elegant).

Comment: Can you please explain how this works?:  sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/jack/jill/2' file

Answer (score 2):

Try this, `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/word1/word2/n' filename`

Here, `:a;N;$!ba` is used to load the entire file into memory, line by line, so that `sed` can process the whole file in a single pass. The `s/word1/word2/N` substitution then replaces every Nth occurrence of `word1` with `word2`.