# search and replace nth occurence in a file

Tags: regex, linux, perl

Does anyone know any unix commands/perl script that would replace  a specific occurence

my file is hello.txt

```
 number         555
 number         555
 number         555
```

now i want to replace the second occurence with number     666.

i have been trying this command

`perl -n -i -e "s/number\\s+555/number   666/g" hello.txt`'

which is changing  all the occurences.

one liners will be really helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I substitute the nth occurrence of a match in a Perl regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555662/how-can-i-substitute-the-nth-occurrence-of-a-match-in-a-perl-regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.` holds line number for current file handle and can be used for given input file like,

```
perl -i -pe 's/number\s+555/number 666/ if $. == 2' hello.txt
```

or if `number` part can be dropped out,

```
perl -i -pe 's/555/666/ if $. == 2' hello.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I read content of file hello.txt to array then joined to get $str. Here it will replace 2nd occurrence with i initialized to 0. Try this search and replace in one liner.

```
 $str =~ s/(number\s+555)/ ++$i==2 ? "number 666": $1/gse;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Does anyone know any unix commands`: I believe `awk` is suitable for this task (http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html).

```
awk '{if (NR == 2) {gsub("555", "666", $0);} print $0; } ' hello.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sed`

```
sed -r -i.bak ':a;N;$!ba;s/(number\s+)555/\1666/2' file
```

Output:

```
 number         555
 number         666
 number         555
```

[Reference SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817798/replacing-nth-occurrence-of-a-string-using-sed)