# Replace Nth String Match In File

Tags: regex, python-3.x, awk, sed, programming-pearls

So I've found many solutions to using `sed s/regexFind/replacement/n` to replace the nth occurence of a word in a line.

For example `s/hello hello hello/world/2` > `hello world hello`

What I'm looking to do however is update the update the third match occurrence over a file.

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

Basically the expectation was that `sed -i s/Hello/world/2 $filename` would replace the file contents to be:

```
Hello
World
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

However this is not the case. Any suggestions?

I'm looking to not use a Python style read-every-line solution, because the file I looking to replace substrings in is not UTF-8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace the nth occurrence of a string using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817798/how-to-replace-the-nth-occurrence-of-a-string-using-sed)

Comment: I know, I posted the solution above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one in GNU awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=/^$/;ORS=""}$0=gensub(/Hello/,"World",2)' file 
Hello
World
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

It treats the whole file as a single record and `gensub` replaces the second match.

Answer (score 0):

**The Solution**

This solution works on Solaris 5.11

*Perl*

`perl-pe 's{Hello}{++$n == 2 ? $& : "World"}ge\' script > tmp && mv tmp script`

*Note: This changes the permissions of the script file. You will likely need to update the permissions using the following command:*

`chmod 777 script`

For more information on file permissions, have a look over the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions)